# Convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I'm set to prove that an AR(1)-process 
$$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+Z_t$$
can be expressed as an MA($\infty$)-process
$$X_t=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi^j Z_{t-j}$$
where $(Z_t)$ is white noise. Now this has a unique solution for $|\phi|<1$. With the use of Kolmogorov's three-series theorem I should be able to prove that $X_t$ is a.s. finite if $(Z_t)$ is i.i.d. white noise. The theorem states:

**Kolmogorov's three-series theorem:** "Let $(X_t)$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and if the following series are convergent
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(|X_t|>\varepsilon),\qquad \sum_{t=1}^\infty EX_t 1_{(|X_t|\leq\varepsilon)},\qquad \sum_{t=1}^\infty VX_t1_{(|X_t|\leq \varepsilon)}$$
then $\sum_{t=1}^\infty X_t$ is a.s. convergent in $\mathbb{R}$."

I've proven the series to be convergent, but my professor keeps saying that in the second series I'm doing something wrong. This is what I've done so far
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty E(\phi^j Z_{t-j} 1_{(|\phi^j Z_{t-j}|\leq\varepsilon)})\leq\sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi^jEZ_{t-j}=0<\infty,$$
since $EZ_t=0$ for all $t$. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using that 
$$
E\left(\phi^j Z_{t-j} 1_{(|\phi^j Z_{t-j}|\leq\varepsilon)}\right)\leqslant \phi^jEZ_{t-j}
$$
but this may not hold, since $Z_{t-j}$ is not always non-negative. However, this can be easily fixed:
$$
\left\lvert E\left(\phi^j Z_{t-j} 1_{(|\phi^j Z_{t-j}|\leq\varepsilon)}\right)\right\rvert\leqslant  E\left(\left\lvert\phi^j Z_{t-j} 1_{(|\phi^j Z_{t-j}|\leq\varepsilon)}\right\rvert\right)\leqslant \lvert \phi\rvert^jE\left( \left\lvert Z_{t-j}   \right\rvert\right)=\lvert\phi\rvert^jE\left( \left\lvert Z_{0}   \right\rvert\right).
$$

Comment: Ofcourse! That will do the trick. Thanks!